# How do I order weekdays with row and column total in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, crosstab, dynamic-pivot

I have a table in which I have some Employee details like id,employeeid,workdate,taskid,hours,entrydate,entryby

And the other table have the basic information about user like firstname,lastname,emailid,password

now I want to create a crosstab query in which I want to display username and the weekday and the working total hours of the employee. 
well first i was thinking to use temp table for this But I failed to do so I use something like this for each day of week

```
select distinct employeeid ,sum(hours) as TotalHours ,'MONDAY' as Day into #Monday from Project_TimeSheet where  year(entrydate)='2014' and month(entrydate)='12' and datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY' group by employeeid
```

But for me this is not working. Anybody please tell me the query for this using pivot I want the result something like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT employeeid,
SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY' THEN hours END) as Monday,
SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,entrydate)='TUESDAY' THEN hours END) as Tuesday,
.....,
sum(hours) as TotalHours
FROM Project_TimeSheet
WHERE  year(entrydate)='2014' and month(entrydate)='12'
GROUP BY employeeid
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: @Azadchouhan use `AND DATEPART ( wk , entrydate )=1..whatever` for a specific week

Comment: please tell me what is  THEN hours End use here?

Comment: @Azadchouhan  IF the datename is monday it SUMs the hours and so on

Comment: @Azadchouhan , you are finding whole month record sso you will always 4-5 weeknumber .

Comment: some of my requirement changes please help me if you have any idea about it this is the link of new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501927/how-to-display-date-as-column-name-in-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample table

[image]

and the sample code

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Name varchar(10), [DATE] datetime,
            TotalHours int)
INSERT #TEMP VALUES 
('A','01/JAN/2014',10), 
('B','02/JAN/2014',20), 
('A','03/JAN/2014',20), 
('B','04/JAN/2014',30), 
('A','05/JAN/2014',40), 
('B','06/JAN/2014',50), 
('A','07/JAN/2014',60),
('A','08/JAN/2014',65),
('Z','07/JAN/2014',72),
('B','15/FEB/2014',70),
('B','16/FEB/2014',50), 
('A','17/FEB/2014',60),
('B','18/FEB/2014',70)
```

Set monday as your First day of the week in Sql Server

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

Insert data into a new table to order the weekedays and bring total as the last column

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])WK
,DATEPART(DW,[DATE]) WDNO
INTO #ORDERTABLE
FROM #TEMP
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL HOURS',8
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Now we do the logic for calculating the total for each Name and Weekdays and bring row-Total in the last row.

```
SELECT 
CASE Name WHEN 'TOTAL BY DAY' THEN 0
          ELSE DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY NAME DESC)
          END RNO,* 
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 'TOTAL BY DAY' ELSE Name END Name,
    CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE]) IS NULL THEN 'TOTAL HOURS' ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE]) END WK,
    SUM(TotalHours)TotalHours   
    FROM #TEMP
    WHERE YEAR([DATE])=2014 AND DATENAME(MONTH,[DATE])='JANUARY'
    GROUP BY Name,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])
    WITH CUBE
)TAB
ORDER BY RNO DESC
```

Select the distinct columns from the `#ORDERTABLE` table

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + WK + ']', 
               '[' + WK + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT WK,WDNO FROM #ORDERTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY WDNO
```

Now pivot the query and order by `RNO`(in which we have applied logic to bring Total in the last row)

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT NAME,' + @cols + ' FROM 
             (
                 SELECT * FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(TotalHours)
                 FOR WK IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p       
            ORDER BY RNO DESC
            ' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

and here is the result

[image]

Here is the SQLFIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/655df/6
(If it shows any error on loading just click RUNSQL button, it will work)

Here is an update where we need to find Startdate and EndDate of that week for a given date(Add the below just after the insertion into #TEMP table)

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE;
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE;

SELECT 
@STARTDATE = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])='MONDAY' THEN [DATE]
      WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])='SUNDAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY,-6,[DATE]) 
      ELSE DATEADD(DAY,-datepart(dw,[DATE])+1,[DATE]) END 
,@ENDDATE = CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])='MONDAY' THEN DATEADD(DAY,6,[DATE])
      WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,[DATE])='SUNDAY' THEN [DATE]
      ELSE DATEADD(DAY,-datepart(dw,[DATE])+7,[DATE]) END 
FROM #TEMP
WHERE [DATE]=CAST('2014-01-06' AS DATE)
```

And use the above variables in the `WHERE` condition(before the CUBE) ie,

```
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Comment: Did you get the answer? @Azad chouhan

Comment: can u please tell me how can I fetch all the week days if any user enter any date for search data for example if any user enter 10 december 2014 then I have to find the startdate and end date of the week using this date

Comment: I have added your update. Please update me when checked @Azad chouhan

Comment: What happened? Is the above query doesn't meet your specification or what is your actual specification? The following query has generated the result for your question with the image. What happaned? Is it not the right answer? @Azad chouhan

Answer (score 0):

try like,

> 

```
    Declare @Year varchar(4)=2014
    Declare @Month varchar(2)=12
    Declare @Input datetime=@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+'01'
    select @input


    select  employeeid 
    ,(Select sum(hours) as TotalHours from Project_TimeSheet M where year(entrydate)='2014' 
    and month(entrydate)='12' and datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY'  and m.employeeid=pts.employeeid  )'MONDAY' 
    from Project_TimeSheet PTS 
    ,(Select sum(hours) as TotalHours from Project_TimeSheet M where year(entrydate)='2014' 
    and month(entrydate)='12' and datename(dw,entrydate)='TUESDAY'  and m.employeeid=pts.employeeid  )'TUESDAY' 
    .....,
    from Project_TimeSheet PTS  
    where  year(entrydate)='2014' and month(entrydate)='12' and datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY' 
    group by employeeid

OR 

select 
SUM(MONDAY)MONDAY,SUM(TUESDAY)TUESDAY
,........
sum(hours)TotalHours
from 
(select  employeeid 
,case WHEN datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY' THEN hours else 0 end 'MONDAY'
,case WHEN datename(dw,entrydate)='TUESDAY' THEN hours else 0 end 'TUESDAY'
,.....
,hours
from Project_TimeSheet PTS  
where  year(entrydate)='2014' and month(entrydate)='12' and datename(dw,entrydate)='MONDAY' 
)tbl
group by employeeid
```