# How to display date as column name in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I worked on a stored procedure in SQL Server few days ago. I created this stored procedure code:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[GetEmployeeHours]  
  (@CurrentDate datetime)
as
begin
   declare @StartDate datetime
   declare @EndDate datetime

   set @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE))
   set @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), CAST(@CurrentDate AS DATE))
   --select @StartDate
   --select @EndDate

   SELECT
     CASE WHEN
      GROUPING(a.firstname +' '+a.lastname)=1 
      THEN 'Total By Day' 
      ELSE 
      a.firstname +' '+a.lastname
       END AS [EmployeeName] ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Monday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Tuesday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as Tuesday,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Wednesday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as WEDNESDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Thursday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as THURSDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Friday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as FRIDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Saturday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as SATURDAY,
    SUM(CASE WHEN datename(dw,workdate)='Sunday' THEN [hours] ELSE 0 END) as SUNDAY,
    SUM(hours) AS [TotalHours]
FROM Project_TimeSheet b  inner join Project_Employee a on b.employeeid =a.id
WHERE workdate >= @StartDate and workdate<= @EndDate
GROUP BY a.firstname +' '+a.lastname 
WITH ROLLUP
end
```

In this stored procedure, I am getting the result of each day and giving the name of week as column name. First I want to use pivot but I found this on stack overflow so I use this. Now I want to display date as column name in the place of week name. Anybody can please tell me how can I do this? I try to do this by assigning the value by declare the variable but all this is not working

Thanks

Comment: get some idea here,try your self.any problem then again ask.
http://forums.asp.net/p/1656473/4315629.aspx?Re+How+to+select+data+datewise+

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use dynamic SQL. If you look for examples of dynamic pivot, you'll quickly find code. But beware, as the application that consumes the results will need to be smart enough to discover the column name...